# prevent/unlock mutex lock of cout

Tags: c++, stream, mutex

My program, which is executed from the command line, looks like this (execute command declared somewhere else):

```
int commandHandler::handleRequest(...)
{
  bool cmdresult = execute(output);
  if cmdresult
  {
    std::cout << output << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The problem:
If you break the ongoing output to cout with ^C, another call to the program will crash at the output to cout, since "cout is locked but the owner is dead".
How do I prevent this in the easiest way? Are there any methods to check if cout is locked before trying to redirect output to that stream, and in that case, unlock it?

If I do a testprogram like this:

```
int  main(void)
{
  std::string output = "Superlongstringwouldbeprinted here... ";
  for(int i=0;i<40000;i++)
    {
      output.append("Superlongstringwouldbeprinted here... ");
    }
  std::cout << output  << std::endl;
}
```

in the "standard" environment, the output is breakable with ^C and I am able to run the program again with output to std::cout. That is, it seems like the implementation of direction to std::cout is flawed in the real time OS I am writing code for?

Comment: I don't see any mutex? Why do you think this is a mutex problem? Where does the `"cout is locked but the owner is dead"` come from?

Comment: From the embedded OS crash dump, which points to the std::cout << output line number.

Answer (score -3):

If you are with C++11, you may use

```
std::mutex::lock() 
std::mutex::try_lock()
std::mutex::unlock()
```

functions.

However, you are not so lucky, you may use platform/library dependent codes

In Linux you can use POSIX mutex.

Another good idea to use scoped locks.

Comment: `^C` is usually not something RAII can recover from.

Comment: Ok, so how to do it then?

Comment: Using exceptions maybe?